# Deleting a row in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I have a loop:

```
for i=1:size(A,1),
   if A(i,4:6) == [0,0,3.4]
      K = [K; A(i,:)];
   end
end
```

and I would like to delete the last row in the matrix but I do not know what number row it will be.  How do I delete the last row in the matrix in the loop?  Or should I do it after the loop?

Comment: The matrix K only has the last row AFTER the loop, right? So you may have to delete last row after the loop.

Comment: If you have to delete it in the loop, you can get the last index in A that A(i,4:6) == [0,0,3.4] using [~,indx]=ismember([0,0,3.4],A,'rows')

Comment: careful when comparing floating-point numbers... Better use: `abs(x-y)<epsilon` (vectorized as: `all(abs(bsxfun(@minus,A,v))<e,2)`)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have loop? it is a one time action, not something you do several times.

check this out, I delete the last row:

```
>> a = magic(5);
>> a

a =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9

>> a = a(1:end-1,:);
>> a

a =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
```

Answer (score 2):

you can refer to last row by END keyword:

```
A= A(1:end-1, :)
```